# how to make IF statement based on one word within a phrase to return another cell's value

Tags: excel

I have this formula:

```
=IF(OR(L7="FOOD",L7="GROCERIES"),K7,0)
```

It only works if for example "FOOD" is the only content. Tonight's Food returns false. I need it to return true regardless of other words.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("FOOD",L7))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("GROCERIES",L7)))),K7,0)
```

Some explanation:

1. `FIND("FOOD",L7)` either finds the word "FOOD" (in capitals) and gives a number, or it yields an error.
2. `ISERROR()` checks for an error or not.

Comment: Kills the problem stone dead. Great result, thank you.

Comment: In case my answer is helpful or solves your problem, please upvote and/or accept it for reference purposes (this is how this site works).

Answer (score 0):

I would always put the criteria in an extra list - in the screenshot below I named that list 'keywords'

Then you can use this formula - if you have Excel 365 (it spills down)
`=BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(d,SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(keywords,d)))))`

Or if you don't have Excel 365 - then you have to drag down
`=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(keywords,A2)))`

You will then use this base formula in your `IF`-statement like this:

`=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords,L7))),K7,0)`

[image]

`FIND` is case-sensitive, `SEARCH` would find "Food" as well.